# How to vertically center individual characters of a text string?

Tags: swift, string, uilabel

I am working on an iPhone app (Swift and Storyboard) and I would like to show some text, e.g. the price of a product people can buy, inside a box, as shown in the image. Nothing special, just an image of a box, with a UILabel on top of it, vertically entered, so the text fits nicely within the box.
This is fine if only numbers are used, but if the text includes (lowercase) letters, the letter is not centered (example in red).

I know that this is how fonts work, and it depends on the baseline and ascender/descender of the character, etc.
But what I would like to do, is vertically center each individual character, so that a text like "200 p" ends up looking like the example in blue.

[image: Example]

I quite extensively searched the internet and tried something myself with UILabel and a little bit of CoreText, but until now didn't find a solution to this.
You would think (well, I would think), that this kind of problem would already been solved, but I am unable to find it.

Does anybody know how to do this? So vertically center the characters in a string so that their (visual) vertical centers line up. Or is there maybe some 3rd party library that is able to do this?

Comment: If you know which characters and which font, your can use `NSAttributedString` to have a different `baseLine` for "p".

Comment: @Larme, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure how this should work in practice? How to set a different baseline for (in this case) "p" and align this with "20"?

Comment: Just a suggestion may not be the perfect solution. We can create our own font from the existing font and change as per your need so that UILabel will read as is

Comment: @RonniedeRakker As per the e.g(Price of the Product) you would know the value and currency then you may have 2 labels, value has no problem, currency to have offset for the base line(label), or we can make currency as an Image for the simplicity.